# Hide specific options in dropdown in symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a form which has these three fields. So in catalogLevelId, I dont need all the data in the dropdown but only some. How to do this?

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('parent', 'entity', array('class' => 'RetailMappingCatalogBundle:Catalog', 'property' => 'title'))
            ->add('catalogLevelId', 'entity', array('class' => 'RetailMappingCatalogBundle:CatalogLevel', 'property' => 'name'))
            ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Submit'))
        ;
    }
```

Comment: what about a query_builder in your option array for the catalogLevelId?

Comment: how do i use the query_builder for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query builder can do this for you, did you already try ?

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

       ->add('catalogLevelId', 'entity',
                            array (
                                    ...,
                                    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                                            return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                                                ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC');
                                        }))
```